# Copying a folder from Communication site to Teams site

Tags: sharepoint-online, ms-flow

I am trying to build a flow what will copy a whole folder along with any sub folders and documents within it from a communication site to a teams site with a manual trigger.

As the folder from the communication site library is a template of documents, which need to be completed when a new project is starts it is constantly updated in the communication site for anyone to use.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Artur

Answer (score 0):

@ArturDj,

There is a built-in action "Copy folder" that could copy a folder from one site to another. it works in a similar way to the "Copy to" command in SharePoint libraries.

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#copy-folder

[image]

BR

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. My only other question is what can I use as a manual trigger and the connection for ‘copy folder’?